# Como quitar slash de una cadena en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Obtengo un texto con JavaScript y lo envió por ajax, pero quiero quitarle todos los slash que pueda traer la cadena como tal y remplazarlos por " - "

Texto que captura en la variable información: Enviar datos a CE/SE al encargado ///Juan o al encargado ////pedro

```
var str = información;
var res = str.replace("/", "-");
alert(res);
```

Con el método anterior mostraría esto :
Enviar datos a CE-SE al encargado ///Juan o al encargado ////pedro

Solo funciona cuando hay un slash claro esta, en el método le he pedido eso, pero no he podido hacer un método que quite todos los slash y los reemplace por "-" si importar la cantidad de slash, esa es mi problemática y seria muy  repetitivo hacer esto

```
var str = información;
var res = str.replace("///", "-");
alert(res);

var str = información;
var res = str.replace("/", "-");
alert(res);

var str = información;
var res = str.replace("////", "-");
alert(res);
```

Intuyendo la cantidad, no quiero hacer eso si no un método que puede hacer todo sin importar la cantidad de slash y cambiar los por "-"

Comment: Echa un vistazo a esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: Gracias este método podría funcionar : str = "///////Test //// test /// test / test /// test...".split("/").join("");

Answer (score 8):

Podrias hacer el replace de esta forma:

```js
var str = "abc/def/ghi/jkm/.../..n";
var res = str.replace(/\//g, "-");
console.log(res);
```

En el primer parametro del replace es una expresion regular, la misma la declaras con dos barra `//`, dentro de esas dos barras colocas la expresion que contendra las reglas, en tu caso nesecitas reemplazar la barra por un guion, pero como la barra (/) afectaria la expresion entonces le antepones una barra invertida para indicar que es un caracter de escape. la `g` al final indica que quieres aplicarlo de forma global.

Tambien puedes intentar utilzar el `new RegExp("/", "g");` mas informacion [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp).

Answer (score 2):

El método de string replace admite expresiones regulares [en MDN puedes investigar más a fondo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) si te llega una cadena en este formato '////Pedro//Carlos/Juan' deberas remplazar los caracteres '/' de manera global, ademas si existen consecutivamente '///' con la expresión "+" estarás requiriendo que también lo saque como grupo de caracteres. Hay que tener especial cuidado pues '/' debe ser escapado con un slash invertido \ quedando asi:

```js
const str = '////Pedro//Carlos/Juan';

const res = str.replace(/\/+/g,'-');

console.log(res);
```

Comment: También es una buena forma gracias (y)

Comment: Entonces con ese ejemplos los slash invertido no los reconoce?  como hago para que incluya ambos? gracias

Comment: const res =   str.replace(/\\/g, "");  Asi tambien funciona?

Comment: si lo que quieres es sacar ambos caracteres "/" y "\" deberas usar conjuntos de caracteres de esta forma: `const res = str.replace(/[\/\\]+/g,'-');`